# Algorithms for controlling low-speed movement of gearless robots

Tags: control, algorithm, movement

Collegues, i am a little discouraged by the lack of a clearly formed section in the literature on which algorithms are used to control the low-speed movement of gearless robots.

In my opinion, it is extremely important to take into account friction, disturbances in the measurement of controlled parameters, etc.

In this case, conventional PI, PID controllers are not suitable.

It seems to me that you need to start by studying specific examples of such systems. For example, I noticed the book [Hard Disk Drive Servo Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781846283048). Robust control is commonly used here.

What pushes me away is that the system can be unsteady and indefinite, and robust synthesis requires an accurate mathematical model.

Perhaps special adaptive algorithms are needed?

Are my arguments true, or is it worth going the other way?
Can anyone advise several sources from which you can begin to study the issue?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you’re looking for...what are low speed gearless robots, what defines low speed ? Please be exactly specific on what you’d like us to help you with. Are you looking for books on nonlinear mathematical modelling? Or programming algorithms and methods for control of said models? I’m not sure what your arguments are, or which ‘other way’ you want to go. Please be specific and i’m sure someone can point you in the right direction

Comment: I'm interested in controlling the low-speed movement of gearless robots. The robot does not have a specific technological purpose, there is only a requirement for movement: moving from point A to point B in a day and turning around the azimuth axis at a speed of one revolution / day. It is necessary to study the control and modeling algorithms of such robots.
I do not know how to formulate this even more specifically.

Comment: Are there special low-speed motion control algorithms?

Comment: So you could just turn a motor on, calculate how far the rotation of the wheels are in linear movement, program that distance, and then once reached rotate and go back? Why do you need to care about anything beyond that? Its difficult for us to give a solution when nothing defined...in your case you could be controlling position via GPS, using an observer to regulate speed or regulating speed and using an observer to control position...or anything. The way you describe your project, i wouldn’t even consider anything beyond which mcu and motor i’d buy and how much weight i need to move.

Comment: We can give concrete answers to concrete problems,  is basically what i’m saying. It’s important if you want to ensure you’re only moving 1cm/hour *always* on the moon while worrying about power consumption. Or if you just have to get to the point you want in around a specific time period. One is far more complex than the other.

Comment: You gave me a couple of useful thoughts and I will try to add specifics. But there are a couple of details that do not need to be paid attention to yet: I am talking about the mass of the moving body and the type of engine used. To the last question I can give such an answer that I plan to experiment with the BLDC motor or other low-speed structures. What interests me the most is the position control structures (including the low-speed one).

Comment: I just can’t get a complete picture of what the structures of such systems should look like, what blocks are included there, what is the role of observers, what are the specifics of controlling low-speed movement, how does the structure change if the parameters of the system are variable, etc. If you can orient me in this and give a link to some simple example, then I would work on it / model it myself, I will be very happy.

Comment: Well, if we talk about some specific features, then this is movement at a very low speed with minimal energy consumption. And I do not need to give a 100% solution to the problem, it is unlikely to exist. I would like to see at least a couple of links to work in this direction, if any.

That's what interests me at the moment, I don’t see how to formulate the question even more specifically.

Comment: In other words, I am well acquainted with the general structure of the position control system, but I know absolutely nothing about how it will change if we need to control super slow motion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104578/discussion-between-morbo-and-dtn).